# ODBC Parameters with List of Values

Tags: vb.net, odbc

A little outside my comfort zone...

Is there any way to pass multiple values (a list of values) to a query via ODBC Parameters in VB.Net?

For instance, is there a way to create a query along the lines of:

-- vb.net has something like Dim itemNumbers As New List(Of Integer)(SomeCount)

```
SELECT Cost, Description
FROM   MyItemList
WHERE  ItemNum IN (<my list of item numbers>)
```

Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337792#337792) seems to apply. Your question is very likely a duplicate of [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/337704)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `ODBCParameter` can hold only a single value. It might be easier to do something like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Cost, Description FROM   MyItemList WHERE  ItemNum IN (@Items)"
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@Items", String.Join(", ", itemNumbers.Select(Function(i) i.ToString())))
```

Comment: I would avoid this approach - it is open to SQL injection.  This is a similar answer that deals with SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/614523